# creating files with IF logic inbeded

Tags: java, android, file-io

Actually two questions:

The main question: 
I hope it isn't true that you can't have simple logic in writing out a file!!!
I have a cursor to load a dynamic list on the screen normally invoked by onCreate.  That works.  Now, I need to write out to the "sdCard" as a back-up.  (If my watch decides to reset to day one, I will reload - it also allows me to add entries from my PC which has a keyboard.)

I decided the best way is to call the existing cursor but set a switch to indicate to write it out.  Files require a try - catch, so I put it around the open, the write, and the close.  The "writers" are undefined.  So I put it all inside one "TRY" that worked if there are no brackets - no "IF"s.

But add "IF (--SWITCH SET)" {---writer.write(strBuRec); ..}" which requires {--} now again the writer is undefined.

I sure hope I am doing something else wrong (probably something stupid)!  I can copy the code into a second cursor, but prefer not to.

Second question:
Note the close cursor (//cursor.close();)  is commented out.  This is because if I repaint the screen or in this case, re-invoke the cursor to write out my file, I get cursor closed.  I can only load the cursor once if I close it.

Note: This is a simple app for my WIMMOne so it needs version 7.  This code is in a fragment, (bad decision, but it's there).

Many thanks,
Clark

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
   {
    Log.d("EventLst","0 LoadFin");
    int iRecNo = 0;
    iBuCnt = 0;
    mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

         //----------------------------------------
         // if exporting, open the file

    try 
       {
        if (strRunBu == "Y")
           {
            FileWriter writer;
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/Event";
            File dir = new File(path);   
            Log.d("Eventfile","00 File:"  + dir);
            File flEvent = new File(dir, "EVENT.TXT");
            boolean canIWrite = dir.canWrite();

            Log.d("Eventfile","0 File:" + flEvent + "=" + canIWrite);
            flEvent.createNewFile();                           
            Log.d("Eventfile","1 File:" + flEvent);
            writer = new FileWriter(flEvent);
           }

             // ------------------------------------------
             // Insert dummy first record to serve as a label
             // 
        String strBuRec = "";
        strRecord.clear();
        strRecord.add(0, "mm-dd-yy: Event name");
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        Log.d("EventLst","1 LoadFin DO");
             // ----------------------------------------
             // Read from cursor and add each record to list 
         while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
           {
            iRecNo = iRecNo + 1;
                 // - Table has 4 columns, read them into string array: strC
            String strC[] = { (cursor.getString(0)), (cursor.getString(1)),
                                  (cursor.getString(2)), (cursor.getString(3))
                            };
                 // - The fourth column is the date/time in milliseconds since
                 // January 1,1970
                 // convert to date in yyyy-mm-dd format
            String strDateMil = (cursor.getString(3));
            long lgDate = cursor.getLong(3);
            Log.d("EventLst","4 LoadCSR:" + "I:" + iRecNo + "Ld:" + lgDate);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");
            String strDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(lgDate));

                 // - Concatenate date and event into one string, add to table
            strRecord.add(iRecNo, strDate + ": " + strC[2]);

                 // - save record number for each event in strRecId
                 // - Records are sorted by date, so we need to save RowId to pass
                 // - to edit screen
            strRecId.add((cursor.getString(0)));

                 //---------------------------
                 // if-creating export file, write a record
            if (strRunBu == "Y")
               {
                dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                String strTime = dateFormat.format(new Date(lgDate));

                strBuRec = ( (cursor.getString(1)) + "," + (cursor.getString(2))
                              + "," + strDate + "," + strTime + "\r\n" );
                Log.d("EventLst","4 LoadCSR:" + "BU:" + strBuRec); 

                       // ERROR:  writer cannot be resolved   ??????????
                writer.write(strBuRec); 
                Log.d("Eventfile","4 File:" + "wrote");
               }

            strEventRec.add(iBuCnt, strBuRec);
            iBuCnt = iBuCnt + 1;

            cursor.moveToNext();
         }    // ----end of while loop
            //------------------------------------
            //  COULD NOT CLOSE THE CURSOR?????
            //cursor.close();
            //------------------------------------
        if (strRunBu == "Y")
           {
            // ERROR:  writer cannot be resolved  ???????????
            writer.flush();
            // ERROR:  writer cannot be resolved  ???????????
            writer.close();
           };
       } //---> BACKTO try 
       catch (IOException e)
          {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Close ER"+ e,
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      Log.d("Eventfile","4 File:" + "Closed");
      strRunBu = "N";

      lstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                   R.layout.event_row, R.id.text1, strRecord);

         // * Call to SetListAdapter()informs ListFragment how to fill ListView
         // * here use ArrayAdapter
    setListAdapter(lstAdapter);
         // Log.d("EventLst","8 LoadCSR:" + "ALLDONE");

   }
```

Comment: That method is impossible to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{` and `}` define scope - you need to make sure the variables are defined in the correct scope. i.e. Not inside the `if` scope, but the one containing the `if`.

Also looks to me like you have far too much in that try-catch block!

Also also: this line `if (strRunBu == "Y")` has the classic rookie mistake of comparing strings with `==` - use `if (strRunBu.equals("Y"))` instead.

Comment: Appreciate the reply.   That’s what I was afraid of, but now I understand why.  I need 2 routines, one to write the records to the CVR file, one to populate the list in the screen.   The “IF” did work in this case, but the last comment explains why it didn’t work in similar code in a different place and how to can fix that.